# When i run cron for a database function it returns me the same value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, cron, drupal-modules

here is the cron code:

```
function blablabla_cron() {
  $i=1; 
  do {
    $gad = blablabla();
    $i++;
  }while ($i<6);
}
```

this code returns me always the same value of the table.

and here is the code of the blablabla function

```
function blablabla() {
  // Begin building the query.
  $query = db_select('watchdog', 'th')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->orderBy('wid')
    ->fields('th')
    ->limit(8)

  // Fetch the result set.
  $result = $query->execute();

  // Loop through each item and add to the $rows array.
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $Severities = unserialize($row->variables);
      if($Severities['%type']) {
        $rows[] = array(
          $row -> wid,
          $Severities['%type'],
        );
      }
  }

  // Headers for theme_table().
  $header = array('ID', 'Message');

  // Format output.
  $output = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows)) . theme('pager');
  return $output;
}
```

what i must do in order when cron runs it will show all the values of the table?

Comment: You should post your real code, in your example `$blabla` is undefined so it is impossible to say what gets added to `$rows`.

Comment: You are passing no argument in `blablabla` function, and same code is being executed each time. So it should return same value.

Comment: how i can correct this problem so?? I am new in drupal code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass that $i to blabla($i) and then use it inside that function to query different range of row your query returns:

Instead of:

```
->limit(8);
```

Use:

```
->range(($i-1)*8,8);
```

That is...if I figured out correctly what you want to achieve here.

https://api.drupal.org/comment/13489#comment-13489

Comment: i have the same problem again it shows me always the same values. It does not go to the next value

Comment: could we do it with a foreach statement?

Comment: Now when cron runs it shows me the same message 5 times

Comment: and when i run cron with this code : function blablabla_cron() {
    $gad = blablabla();
}             when i press cron many times it shows me the values that i want

Comment: With my change (I assume that you added $i parameter to your function and that you are passing it from your loop) your blabla() will be called 5 times and 1st time will display results 0-7, second 8-15 and so on. Is that what you want?

Comment: yeah but bit it get me out 7 times the 0 item

Comment: i made the changes look on the top code and tell me if i must do something different....thank you very much!!

Comment: and i am sure that the messages are different

Comment: it not become somehow with the foreach statement?

Comment: Debug it. Write out $i, write out $result from within the function. Find out where the problem is.

Comment: i am new in drupal i do not know how to do this thing :'(

Comment: That's not a drupal thing. Just add echo $i; or print_r($result); Write out variable or array content to see what you have in it.